# Flutter media recorder amplitude

Tags: flutter, mediarecorder, amplitude, decibel, meter

I am building a shot clock which needs to be able to stop a timer when the microphone detects a loud noise. 
There seems to be no libraries out there that can grab amplitude like in MediaRecorder for android.
i have searched the web the last week and can't find any plugins or libraries that can help me out. Does anyone have a solution?
Cheers from Australia